# Constructor definition without implementation?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working with a library that is not written by myself.
Some classes have constructors in their header files declared that look like

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    SomeClass(const SomeClass& orig);

    // more declarations

}
```

But there is no implementation in the .cpp file. Why does the code compile anyway?

Comment: This does not seem like a constructor as it is named differently from the class it is in.

Comment: Those are declarations. A definition will have an implementation.

Comment: That's a declaration, not a definition. And definitions aren't needed for compilation in a lot of cases, only linking.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes it also linked, I tried to use it with boost.python which then lead to an error (undefined symbol) when importing the library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code will compile and link if the function is never used.

What you have is a reasonably common if a little old-fashioned way of forbidding object deep copies: If the compiler attempts to take one then the linker will fail.

These days, you can use C++11 constructor `delete` idioms:

```
SomeClass(const SomeClass& orig) = delete;
```

Comment: Though usually the constructor would be private, not public as shown here.

Comment: Indeed. The OP's class is particularly antisocial - forcing a developer to wait for complete compilation before getting a considerably more cryptic error.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Or maybe the original was indeed `private` and the OP, not understanding the importance of this `private` used `public` when he recreated an example from scratch. (I kinda doubt the original class was named `SomeClass`)

Answer (score 5):

This is one way to disable the copy constructor for the class. Typically, the declaration is made `private` too (you then at least get a nice access modifier error, rather than a linker error).

The C++11 way to do this is as follows:

```
SomeClass(const SomeClass& orig) = delete;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you never call constructor in your code, or use this class / struct, there is no need to have implementation.